# Gradle rule for Android

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

Is it possible to use a Gradle Rule (Or more than a single one) to replace values in resources?
I'm aware that this is something that flavors would do well but I need to have lots of values that must be changed as a build configuration and i though that Gradle rules would solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot modify the contents of resources readily through anything currently in Gradle for Android.

You can use product flavors or build types to *replace* resources by means of having the replacement resources in the appropriate sourceset (e.g., in `src/debug/` for the `debug` build type).

You are also welcome to attempt to write a Gradle plugin or otherwise create a Gradle task that you insert into the build sequence that modifies some `intermediates` copy of the resources and ensures that this copy is what is included in the actual build.